# psexec cannot run .vbs local or unc

Tags: windows, remote, vbscript

I am trying to run a .vbscript remotely via `psexec`. Even with switches like -u -p -s -c, I am getting errors. Here is what I've tried:

1.)

```
psexec  -u user@domain -p password -s \\computer  "\\uncpath\file.vbs"

"access denied"
```

I have seen that to resolve this issue you can add reg key to host and reboot. This is not an option for me.

Next I tried the copy switch for localpath.

2.)

```
psexec  -u user@domain -p password  -s \\computer  -c "C:\localpath\file.vbs"
"The system cannot find the file specified"
```

So how can I run a .vbs script via psexec?

Comment: Have you tried using cscript to run the vbs?

Comment: Maybe my syntax's is wrong? cmd exited error 1 psexec  -u user@domain -p password -s \\computer cmd /c cscript "\\uncpath\file.vbs"

Comment: ok removing the switch -s (system) made the script work. I think? All I see is cscript header and no output. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out.

- Had to take out -s switch. 
  -used cscript
- used cscript /nologo switch.

  psexec  -u user@domain -p password \\computer cscript /nologo "\uncpath\file.vbs"